# Angular2 NgSwitch confusion - it matches case AND default?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm having trouble figuring out why my ngswitch isn't working.

```
<div [ngSwitch]="notification.type">
    <div *ngSwitchWhen="'videoready'">
        <p>Video Goes Here</p>
        <p item-right>{{notification.added | date:'MMM'}}</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchWhen="'friendrequest'">
        <p>Friend Request</p>
        <p>{{notification.added | date:'MMM'}}</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchDefault>
        <p>{{notification.message}}</p>
        <p item-right>{{notification.added | date:'MMM'}}</p> <!-- adding the date pipe here BREAKS everything -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The notification definitely has an `added` date in the default case, it's the same date object as the others.
The other odd thing is:  if I leave the `ngSwitchDefault` in, and comment out the others (so only the default is left) then the date pipe works just fine.
It's as if the ngSwitch is matching 2 states at once, and gets.... confused.

```
<div [ngSwitch]="notification.type">
    <!-- leaving the others out works just fine -->
    <div *ngSwitchDefault>
        <p>{{notification.message}}</p>
        <p item-right>{{notification.added | date:'MMM'}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5169

Pipe in `*ngSwitchDefault` currently doesn't work.